# How to make docker-compose services accesible with each other?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a frontend app accesible to the outside. It depends on several other modules, serving as services/backend. This other services also rely on things like Kafka and OpenLink Virtuoso (Database).

How can I make all of them all accesible with each other and how should I expose my frontend to outside internet? Should I also remove any "localhost/port" in my code, and replace it with the service name? Should I also replace every port in the code for the equivalent port of docker?

Here is an extraction of my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '2'
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ports:
          - 22181:2181

    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        ports:
            - 29092:29092
        environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
   frontend:
       build:
          context: ./Frontend
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
       image: "jcpbr/node-frontend-app"
       ports:
          - "3000:3000"
       # Should I use links to connect to every module the frontend access and for the other modules as well?
       links: 
           - "auth:auth"
    auth:

      build:
          context: ./Auth
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      image: "jcpbr/node-auth-app"
      ports:
          - "3003:3003" 
   (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make all of [my services] all accesible with each other?

Do absolutely nothing.  Delete the obsolete `links:` block you have.  Compose automatically creates a network named `default` that you can use to communicate between the containers, and they can use the other Compose service names as host names; for example, your `auth` container could connect to `kafka:9092`.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

(Some other setups will advocate manually creating Compose `networks:` and overriding the `container_name:`, but this isn't necessary.  I'd delete these lines in the name of simplicity.)

> How should I expose my frontend to outside internet?

That's what the `ports: ['3000:3000']` line does.  Anyone who can reach your host system on port 3000 (the first port number) will be able to access the `frontend` container.  As far as an outside caller is concerned, they have no idea whether things are running in Docker or not, just that your host is running an HTTP server on port 3000.

Setting up a reverse proxy, maybe based on Nginx, is a little more complicated, but addresses some problems around communication from the browser application to the back-end container(s).

> Should I also remove any "localhost/port" in my code?

Yes, absolutely.

> ...and replace it with the service name? every port?

No, because those settings will be incorrect in your non-container development environment, and will probably be incorrect again if you have a production deployment to a cloud environment.

The easiest right answer here is to use environment variables.  In Node code, you might try

```js
const kafkaHost = process.env.KAFKA_HOST || 'localhost';
const kafkaPort = process.env.KAFKA_PORT || '9092';
```

If you're running this locally without those environment variables set, you'll get the usually-correct developer defaults.  But in your Docker-based setup, you can set those environment variables

```yaml
services:
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    environment:
       KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092  # must match the Docker service name
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      KAFKA_HOST: kafka
      # default KAFKA_PORT is still correct
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry if my question sounds a bit dumb, but I'm to Docker. For another module to access another, should I do, for example,  `code const authHost = process.env.AUTH_HOST || 'localhost'; const kafkaPort = process.env.AUTH_PORT|| '3003'; `

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend that approach.

Comment: OK! I will try that way and get back to you, if thats ok

Comment: @ZéBrasa You probably meant `const authPort`. Don't override `kafkaPort` variable